# How to regenerate initramfs so it can include bcache module?

Tags: kernel-modules, initramfs, bcache

Eventually I have converted root-fs into bcache (with the help of `blocks`). I skipped the step `update-initramfs -u -k all` because I've been using bcache on other partitions for some time, and I've wrongly assumed, that the appropriate kernel module must have been in the initramfs already.

The system doesn't boot; instead it shows me the initramfs prompt, and I cannot see bcache neither on `/sys/fs/bcache` nor on `cat /proc/modules`; so I assume that the module is loaded on the later stages.

Normally I'd boot into liveCD and rebuild the initramfs from there with the `chroot` trick. Unfortunately I know no Linux live CD with bcache support, so I have no hope of mounting the root partition other way, than buing new hard drive and installing a Linux there so it can be a platfrom for repairing the main Linux... And playing with two Linux installations would take a lot of extra time and addtitional risk that I might screw another thing up.

Is there anything I can do without buing a new hard drive? Maybe someone know a liveCD that supports bcache?

I use Linux Mint Cinnamon 16 64bit with separate boot partition.

---

Update:

The installation of `bcache-tools` from the "official" `bcache ppa:g2p/storage` does indeed install the required `bcache` modules. Except that if you have more then 1 kernel on /boot it applies it only to the most recent kernel. In my case I had two kernels: 3.11 from official the Ubuntu Saucy sources, and second mainline kernel 3.12 (which isn't compatible with Cinnamon 2.0 somehow). Only the 3.12 kernel got the bcache module included in the initramfs.

Answer (score 2):

Once I've discovered, that the first kernel (which isn't the default on my setup) got the bcache modules loaded, I switched into it and as root issued

```
# update-initramfs -u -k all

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.12.11-031211-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
```

just as I should have done it from the very beginning.

After that all kernel modules got updated and problem is solved.